# Get properties of first and last child nodes in SKNode parent

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, sknode

If I use the below, I can loop through the child objects in my SKNode parent and it works fine to get the position in the scene

```
for child in platformGroup.children {
            let posInScene = self.convertPoint(child.position, fromNode: platformGroup)
            println("Pos in scene \(posInScene)")

        }
```

When I attempt to the position property from the first or last child in the node I get an error.

```
    let lastPlatPos = self.convertPoint(platformGroup.children.last?.position! , fromNode: platformGroup)
    println(lastPlatPos.x)
```

> Error: Value of optional type 'CGPoint' not unwrapped, did you mean to
>   use '!' or '?'?

What am I missing here?

Even if I wrap it I get the same error:

```
if let lastPlatPos = self.convertPoint(platformGroup.children.last?.position! , fromNode: platformGroup) {
    println(lastPlatPos.x)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My mistake, it was the ? Optional on last that was the issue

```
let lastPlatPos = self.convertPoint(platformGroup.children.last!.position, fromNode: platformGroup)
```

This works